# How to get an array out of a nav menu if it's a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, menus

I want to get an `array` out of my new created menu as part of a new plugin, but it turns out to be very tricky.

Why I'm getting a boolean `false` for everything (`object`, `array`, `items`) except for `wp_nav_menu()`?

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'register_omaha_menu' );
function register_omaha_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'omahamenu', __( 'Omaha Menu' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'get_link_to_pages' );
function get_link_to_pages() {

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'omahamenu' ) ); // This is working. Output: Omaha Menu
    $menuooo = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'Omaha Menu' ); // Not working. Why? Output: /srv/www/.../web/app/plugins/omaha/omaha.php:--:boolean false
    var_dump( $menuooo ); // Not working. Why? Output: /srv/www/.../web/app/plugins/omaha/omaha.php:--:boolean false
    var_dump( wp_get_nav_menu_object( 'omahamenu' ) ); // Not working. Why? Output: /srv/www/.../web/app/plugins/omaha/omaha.php:--:boolean false
    var_dump( get_term_by( 'omahamenu', NULL, 'nav_menu' ) ); // Not working. Why? Output: /srv/www/.../web/app/plugins/omaha/omaha.php:--:boolean false

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a theme location, you need to first get the menu assigned to that location to get its items:

```
if( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() )
    && isset( $locations[ 'omahamenu' ] ) ) {
        $menuooo = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $locations['omahamenu'] );
        var_dump( $menuooo );
}
```